# IsolatedStorageSettings class object local folder location

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

I'm working on windows phone 8.1 silverlight and using IsolatedStorageSettings for local storage. It's working fine and also I'm getting the modified values when device is rebooted. My question is how can I get to know the location of the storage. If I want to make any modification in the storage location, is that possible?

Comment: Do you not specify the folder name and location when you read/write? Do you mean that you want to move the folder?

Comment: I don't specify the folder name and I want to know the path so that I can move/modify it.

Comment: Is there any way to implement the above?
Thanks,

Comment: If you don't specify a folder you're files are stored in the root folder of your app: "The root of the virtual file system is located in a per-user, obfuscated folder on the physical file system." [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: why would you want to modify it in any other way that using its standard api?